# Using schtasks /z switch to delete tasks

Tags: windows-7, taskscheduler

I am trying to use `schtasks` to schedule a python GUI script. I want to delete a task once it has run. According to the documentation, I should be using the `/Z` switch along with the `/V1` switch. But this asks for a run-as password which I can't figure out how to provide. 
The command that I am using is:

```
schtasks /create /sc once /tn task2 /tr "reminder i26" /sd 31/05/2017 /st 
23:00 /V1 /Z /F
```

What is the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the doc below. It shows the /z switch as being valid to delete a scheduled task. Since you’re using “/sc once”, It may believe that no schedule exists since it’s running on demand. I get an xml error when trying /z on Windows 10 in a similar situation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by allowing the use of blank passwords in all cases. As I am on Windows 7 Home Basic, there is no security policy editor (no secpol.msc). So I had to change the following registry setting -

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\limitblankpassworduse:
0x00000000
```

But it seems that the /z switch is not working - tasks are not getting automatically deleted on completion (at least not on windows 7 Home Basic).